# pure css: make a nested div pop out under its parent

Tags: html, css, nested

I have a website where some teaser text and a button are presented on a background image.

grosso modo:

```
<div class="background">
<div class="teaser">
Teaser text
</div>
</div>
```

In an effort to make a website responsive, this teaser text and button should appear underneath the div rather on top, because the image makes it difficult to read on smaller print. How can I make this nested div appear underneath? I tried using position: relative but then it won't take up space below the div, overlapping other content.

Answer (score 1):

You say you've tried `position: relative`... Have you tried `position: absolute` on the nested div?

```css
.background {
  background-image: url(http://s3.india.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/species1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.teaser {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="teaser">
    Teaser text
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  More content outside of teaser.
</div>
```

The `teaser` is `position: absolute` to its nearest `position: relative` parent (`.background`). I've position: it `-20px` from the bottom of `background` and added 20px of margin to the bottom of `background` as compensation so `teaser` doesn’t overlap other content.

Comment: That indeed works, but I can't set a pixel height for my teaser as the text length may vary. This means that I cannot set the margin-bottom nor position the teaser at -20px from the bottom.

Comment: instead of using background you could use img, or use js